# Narrowing down type using type predicate based on second parameter

Tags: typescript

I have a validation function that receives a value to validate and it also receives configuration object to use for the validation.

```js
const config = {type: 'foo'}
const value = {name: 'John', age: 22}

const isValid = (value: Value, config: Config) {
  // some validation over here
}
```

The value is of a union of two types. I'd like the validation function to not only validate the value based on the config but also to narrow down the type of the value to one of the two types of the union.

```js
type Value = Foo | Bar
```

I know to which of the two to narrow down based on the configuration. The logic should be like this:

- If `config.type` is `foo` and the validation function returns true it should be type `Foo`
- If `config.type` is `bar` and the validation function returns true it should be type `Bar`
- If the validation returns false, the type should remain to be `Value`

Examples:

```js
type Config = {type: 'foo' | 'bar'}
type Foo = {name: string, age: number, something?: string}
type Bar = {name: string, age: number, somethingElse?: string}
type Value = Foo | Bar
const value: Value = {name: 'John', age: 22}

const config: Config = {type: 'foo'}
if (isValid(value, config)) {
 // value should be narrowed down to Foo
}

const config2: Config = {type: 'bar'}
if (isValid(value, config2)) {
 // value should be narrowed down to Bar
}
```

Question is, how should I modify the `isValid` function so it narrows down the type based on the config and the return value?

Note that the config is constant in the code (though there are multiple different configs).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQ24nN) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, it looks promising. I need to try and apply it on my actual use case which is bit more complex, but will get back to you asap :)

Comment: @jcalz Alright, it works! Thank you! If you put it into an answer I will accept it. I have two optional bonus questions. a) My config isn't just the `type` property. What would be the best way to type the predicate? `config: Config & {type: K}` seems to work. b) I have actually more types than just two. I have two for which it is the first type, and many more for which it is the second. Is it possible to modify it so it narrows it to the first type for the given two values and the second type for all the rest without having to specify them all in the map?

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance. I could probably do something with those bonus questions given a [mre] but without it I’m not sure how to advise exactly (you could probably use a conditional type instead of a map lookup)

Comment: Added MRE for the second thing. Thanks.

Comment: Ah I didn't mean the bonus question should be added here; putting two questions in one post risks closure for the reason "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."  You might want to either move this out to a new post or change the question to use just the new version. The latter is arguably scope creep but at least it's one question.

Comment: [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZ199N) is what I'd do for the bonus version, wherever it ends up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the question as asked, I'd be inclined to make `isValid()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `K`, the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) of the `type` property of the `config` argument, and have the [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) narrow `value` by [looking up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `K` in an appropriate mapping interface:

```
interface ValMap {
    foo: Foo,
    bar: Bar
}
declare const isValid: <K extends keyof ValMap>(
    value: Value,
    config: { type: K }
) => value is ValMap[K]
```

Then we can use it like this:

```
declare const value: Value;

const config = { type: 'foo' } satisfies Config;
if (isValid(value, config)) {
    value; // Foo
    value.something
}

const config2 = { type: 'bar' } satisfies Config;
if (isValid(value, config2)) {
    value; // Bar
    value.somethingElse;
}
```

Note that we can't just write `const config = {type: "foo"}`, or the compiler will infer it to have type `{type: string}`, which is too wide to be useful and isn't even assignable to `Config`.  There are different ways to get the compiler to infer something more appropriate; you could use [a `const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the initializer, or you could do what I did above and use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to provide the context that you're trying to get a `Config`-compatible type (without actually widening all the way to `Config` which wouldn't be useful either).

Anyway, it looks good... when `isValid()` returns `true` it narrows `value` to `Foo` or `Bar` in the right places.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false&ssl=15&ssc=24&pln=14&pc=18#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeVSQBcUA5EnHCVAD6kBGAhgE5UC+AUAdAGIVa5QEDALYRiAZ2BMUCNABooDNGMEBXYXQhMF4uKOAALGWgD8EqcagcuUAELN+eIaPPTZCpSoTrN2qLv0jWQBRABtxCDN-C1krdk5waAA1BlDVaGxeOBo7ZniAEwgAY1DmaCLESSgAN1T04hS0iABueJlgLSQGIuTUgFkGMFx2KFGocjhiLLkRscYmYnsmdg5CkrKoCoQqlHFGlHziAB4AaSgIAA8OhHzxKABrCBA4JChGgbAAPgAKWdHapoNOoQGZjTaIVBoYh4LjEM4cACUWE+NWBUF2b36gwA2icALrxLZVLaQxz4RLEMgUNj+BjAXaoCB3eDIdCtFCvb67fb5b4A9IKEnoBFInB-VFNZpQAD00qgWXF-IgADoAhBDMYVoTKsBway0AAmMmw+jMGniOkMlBM2AQtnsDlQLl7VIHPnAwV2w0i4ZgpVS2W5ZZ+4GqvTqoJoMIRVocIA)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve something like this?

```
type Foo = { name: string; age: number; something?: string };
type Bar = { name: string; age: number; somethingElse?: string };
type Value = Foo | Bar;
const value: Value = { name: "John", age: 22 };

type Config<T extends Value> = { type: "foo" | "bar" };

const isValid = <T extends Value>(
  value: Value,
  config: Config<T>
): value is T => {
  return false;
};

const config: Config<Foo> = { type: "foo" as const };
if (isValid(value, config)) {
  // value should be narrowed down to Foo
  console.log(value);
}

const config2: Config<Bar> = { type: "bar" };
if (isValid(value, config2)) {
  // value should be narrowed down to Bar
  console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: There is no `type` property on Foo/Bar types. The validation can tell through lots of checks which one it is (that is why I am relying on it being truthy), but I can't use the properties of value for the narrowing.

Comment: @MartinKadlec is type property static in your case?
In case of static value, [this](https://tsplay.dev/N550oN) may be what you need (I've updated my answer)